# Synthesis of 2,3-dihydrobenzo[b][1,4]dioxin-2-yl)(piperazin-1-yl)methanone

Tags: organic-chemistry

My interest regarding Doxazosin made me curious, what's an easy way to synthesis Doxazosin. The first part is 2-chloro-6,7-dimethoxyquinazolin-4-amine. However, I would like to find a simple synthesis 2,3-dihydrobenzo[b][1,4]dioxin-2-yl)(piperazin-1-yl)methanone in order to get Doxazosin. I tried to form a synthesis, however it looks not very effective (too many steps, etc.).

My questions:

Is there an easier method?

Are there critical errors in my synthesis?

[image]

1. methyl acrylate bromation
2. formation the 1,4-dioxane via pyrocatechol
3. cleavage of the methyl group with LiOH
4. forming an acetylchloride
5. piperidine

I edited/ improved the steps with the help of Zhe.

Comment: The biggest issue I see here is that step 3 probably results in a Baeyer-Villager oxidation, which is not what you want. Probably easier is to start from methyl acrylate and then remove the methyl group with LiOH after cyclization. Steps 5 and 6 seem unnecessarily complicated. Just add the acyl chloride to an excess of piperidine (it's pretty cheap), and you should get very little of the double addition.